# Why is this Objective-C code leaking memory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

Why does this leak?

The `arrayOfPerformances` is a `NSMutableArray`, `(nonatomic, retain)` property that is synthesized.

The `currentPerformanceObject` is a `Performance *`, `(nonatomic, retain)` property that is synthesized.

`Performance` is a custom class

```
if(self.arrayOfPerformances == nil)
    {
        self.arrayOfPerformances = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    [self.arrayOfPerformances addObject:currentPerformanceObject];
    [currentPerformanceObject release];
    currentPerformanceObject = nil;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are creating a new array *and* retaining it at the same time in this line, because you are invoking a `(retain)` property setter with the dot notation:

```
// Your property
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrayOfPerformances;

// The offending code
self.arrayOfPerformances = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Because of that, the locally-created array is leaking because you don't release it. You should autorelease that array, or create a temporary local var, assign, then release the local var, like so:

```
// Either this
self.arrayOfPerformances = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

// Or this (props Nick Forge, does the same as above)
self.arrayOfPerformances = [NSMutableArray array];

// Or this
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.arrayOfPerformances = newArray;
[newArray release];
```

Comment: What Nick said;  use `[NSMutableArray array]`

Comment: Wow, that setter really messed my mind. I combed my code for hours trying to figure out where the leak was and finally isolated that code and could  not figure out for the life of me what was going wrong. Thanks a million!

Comment: @Mausimo: Glad I got it finally tracked down :)

Answer (score 4):

If your `.arrayOfPerformances` property is never released (it would usually be released in `-dealloc`), than the array itself, plus any object in the array will be leaked when this object is dealloced.

You need to release both properties in your `-dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    ... other deallocs
    self.arrayOfPerformances = nil;
    self.currentPerformanceObject = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Also, as @BoltClock has pointed out, you need to release or auto-release your `NSMutableArray`. The best way to do this is to initialize it using the autoreleased method:

```
self.arrayOfPerformances = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Also, you don't need to release your `currentPerformanceObject`, you should just set the property to nil, since setting the `retain`ed property to `nil` will release it for you. Your code should probably look something like this:

```
if (self.arrayOfPerformances == nil) {
    self.arrayOfPerformances = [NSMutableArray array];
}
[self.arrayOfPerformances addObject:self.currentPerformanceObject];
self.currentPerformanceObject = nil;
```

Comment: I keep forgetting about that `array` method :)

Answer (score 1):

This line is the culprit:

```
self.arrayOfPerformances = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

The retain count is 1 after the alloc/init.  Setting the value via the `arrayOfPerformances` property setter increments the retain count again (because it's a retain property).